# Show default windows mouse cursor on top of other full screen applications with Autohotkey

Tags: windows-8, autohotkey, mouse-cursor

Is there a way to show the default windows mouse cursor on top of other full screen applications with Autohotkey? I mean some raster image programs in full screen automatically hide default windows cursor, I will like to display the default windows cursor all the time inside those applications.

Thanks advanced.

Comment: This might help. http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/32608-changing-the-system-cursor/

Comment: thanks, pls any other hint?

Comment: Sorry I'm on my cellphone... Try this maybe? `DllCall("ShowCursor",UInt,1)`

Comment: How does it work? Do I have to paste that code somewhere? Thanks advanced.

Comment: just run it as a would a command. Just paste on a line.

Comment: I pasted inside an AHKscript, run it, but it does not show the cursor on top of other full screen application.

Comment: hmm.. maybe if you tried this script? http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/DllCall.htm#HideCursor

Comment: Did the script work for you?